# Can DevOps - Maven Task skip or delay integration tests during the day?

Tags: maven, azure-devops

Microsoft suggested I create a feature request since Maven Task apparently is incapable of skipping integration tests during the day.  Consequently, for a large Java project DevOps is useless:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/973162/maven-task-delay-or-skip-integration-tests-during.html

Comment: Please check this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), what's the real question of this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately my SSCCE is comprised of my entire 2M+ LOC monolith project with hundreds of tests, building on Azure DevOps, which takes hours to run all the integration tests but otherwise compiles and unit tests quickly.  I don't want to disable unit tests and at present decomposing the monolith into manageable projects isn't an option.  I'll close my question since SO can't handle it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow can't answer difficult Azure DevOps questions.